# Separate Array list based on object's field

Tags: java, list

I have a class `Obj` like :

```java
public class Obj{
    private String size
    private String shape
    private String name
}
```

In one of my other classes I have a `Map<String,List<Obj>>`.
For each `String` in my `Map`, I want to regroup every `Obj` from my List where `shape` and/or `size` are equals, based on the `String` of my `Map`.
For now I have something like :

```java
functionName(Map<String, List<Obj>> objMap){
    objMap.foreach((type,objs) -> {
        switch(type){
            case "type_1":
                // regroup objs by shape
                // then do some treatment
            case "type_2":
                // regroup objs by size
                // then do some treatment
            case "type_3":
                // regroup objs by shape & size
                // then do some treatment
        }
    }
}
```

From here I'm kinda stuck on how to get a `List<List<Obj>>` from my `List<Obj>`.
Any idea would help me, even if not very optimized.

**Values and expected result :**

For example I have a Map as :

```
{
  "key" :"type_1",
  "value" : [
    {
      "size" : "m1",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_1"
    },
    {
      "size" : "m2",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_2"
    },
    {
      "size" : "m3",
      "shape" : "s2",
      "name":"Obj_3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in my function I should be in `case "type_1"` so i'll group them by shape, return me something like :

```
[
  [
    {
      "size" : "m1",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_1"
    },
    {
      "size" : "m2",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_2"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "size" : "m3",
      "shape" : "s2",
      "name":"Obj_3"
    }
    
  ]
]
```

But if my `key` was `type_3`, I should have :

```
[
  [
    {
      "size" : "m1",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "size" : "m2",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_2"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "size" : "m3",
      "shape" : "s2",
      "name":"Obj_3"
    }
  ]
]
```

because none of them have the same `shape` and `size`

If my Map was  :

```
{
  "key" :"type_3",
  "value" : [
    {
      "size" : "m1",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_1"
    },
    {
      "size" : "m2",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_2"
    },
    {
      "size" : "m1",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_3"
    }
  ]
}
```

then I should get :

```
[
  [
    {
      "size" : "m1",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_1"
    },
    {
      "size" : "m1",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_3"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "size" : "m2",
      "shape" : "s1",
      "name":"Obj_2"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what exactly you want to archive. Maybe add some more explanation and an example input plus expected ouput.

Comment: Ok, i'm working on it

Comment: Stream, group by, put values of grouped map into list(s)

Comment: @knittl took a look, based on [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector), it only seems to group by on field, and it returns a Map, so I'm not sure about it

Comment: there's groupingBy function for that

Comment: @Neo yes, group by your fields (create a new `Key`/`Tuple` class or use `Map.Entry`), then use `.values()` on the map.

Comment: @Neo I think you are looking for the items to be sorted by "size" and "shape" within each _type_.

Comment: And forget about the Key/Tuple, you are only grouping by a single property, so this can serve as a grouping key. `Collectors.groupingBy` is perfect for this; as is illustrated by the answers.

Comment: The switch statement + loop is unnecessary. You already have the data structure for that, a Map. `List<Obj> type_1 = objMap.get("type_1");`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create nested `Map<String, Map<String, List<Obj>>>` to store values after grouping.

For example:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, List<Obj>>> results = new HashMap<>();
```

Although, I would create another class for grouped records to make the code more readable:

```java
class GroupedObj{
   Map<String, List<Obj>> records = new HashMap<>(); 
}

Map<String, GroupedObj> results = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a `List<List<Obj>> finalList`. Keep a map to trace the index of the list for certain type in the finalList.

`Map<String, Integer> indexMap;`

Whenever you get a object of type1, try to get list like this

`List<Obj> l1 = indexMap.getOrElse(new ArrayList());`

Then append the object to that list and put back in index of the final list.

```
        List<List<Obj>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        functionName(Map<String, List<Obj>> objMap){
            objMap.foreach((type,objs) -> {
                switch(type){
                    case "type_1":
                        Integer index = indexMap.getOrDefault(type_1, -1);
                        List<Obj> list = index != -1 ? finalList.get(index) : new ArrayList<Obj>();
                        list.add(obj);
                        finalList.add(index, list); // do this for other types
                        // regroup objs by shape
                        // then do some treatment
                    case "type_2":
                        // regroup objs by size
                        // then do some treatment
                    case "type_3":
                        // regroup objs by shape & size
                        // then do some treatment
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Case for shape (but you get the idea):

```
 List<List<Obj>> regroup(List<Obj> objs) {
    return new ArrayList<>(
       objs.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getShape))
         .values()
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `groupingBy` collector:

```
Map<String, List<Obj>> yourMap = ...;
List<List<Obj>> byShape = new ArrayList<>(yourMap.values().stream()
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getShape))
  .values());
```

As a method:

```
static <T> List<List<Obj>> partition(
    final Map<String, List<Obj>> map,
    final Function<? super Obj, ? extends T> key) {
  return new ArrayList<>(map.values().stream() // Stream<List<Obj>>
      .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<Obj>
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(key)) // Map<T, List<Obj>>
      .values() // Collection<List<Obj>>
  ); // List<List<Obj>>
}
```

Calling the method:

```
final Map<String, List<Obj>> yourMap = ...;
final List<List<Obj>> shapes = partition(yourMap, Obj::getShape);
```

If you have extracted the list only and do not need to process a map – in that case the "map"-part is irrelevant for the question and should/could be removed – the method looks almost identical (the classic "left as an exercise to the reader", but here it goes):

```
static <T> List<List<Obj>> partition(
    final List<Obj> list,
    final Function<? super Obj, ? extends T> key) {
  return new ArrayList<>(list.stream() // Stream<Obj>
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(key)) // Map<T, List<Obj>>
      .values() // Collection<List<Obj>>
  ); // List<List<Obj>>
}
```

Usage:

```
final List<Obj> yourList = ...;
final List<List<Obj>> shapes = partition(yourList, Obj::getShape);
```